# Investigate the convergence of given double integral. A solution with kind request of checking it.

Tags: integration, analysis

Let $D=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\colon x^2+y^2\le x\}$. Investigate the convergence of $\iint_D (x^2+y^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\: d(x,y)$.

---

My solution:

Since $f(x,y):=(x^2+y^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ is defined and continuous everywhere except $(0,0)$, for any $\varepsilon>0$ the integral over $D\setminus B$ is finite, where $B=B((0,0),\varepsilon)$.

The integral over $D\cap B$ is finite, since
$$
\iint_{D\cap B} (x^2+y^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\: d(x,y) \le \iint_{B} (x^2+y^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\: d(x,y) = \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\varepsilon}(r^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}r\: dr\: d\varphi=2\pi\varepsilon
$$

Is it a complete and correct solution?

Comment: It looks fine to me. If you are an overachiever you can also compute the integral in a explicit way.

Answer (score 0):

First note that you can rewrite $D$ as 
$$x^2-x+y^2\le0$$
$$x^2-x+\frac{1}{4}+y^2\le \frac{1}{4}$$
$$\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+y^2\le \frac{1}{4}$$

which is just a circle of radius $r=\frac{1}{2}$ centered around $\left(\frac{1}{2},0 \right)$. Knowing this, you can explicitly calculate the integral in polar coordinates quite easily (I'll leave that part for you to do).